# GMSH into su2 mesh file issue

Tags: gmsh

### thanks in advance for any help provided.
Ive been trying to run a simple case through su2 where im analysing the flow over the d8 aircraft, ive modelled the aircraft in openvsp, meshed the model in gmsh and am currently attempting to run it in su2. However su2 is having trouble reading the mesh file and initially outputs this error:
Error in "void CPhysicalGeometry:istributeColoring(const CConfig *, CGeometry *)":

Mismatch between NPOIN and number of points listed in mesh file.
Please check the mesh file for correctness.

------------------------------ Error Exit -------------------------------
through trial and error ive found that this error can be fixed by artificially adding one digit to the "NPOIN" numbe------------------- Geometry Preprocessing ( Zone 0 ) -------------------

### Error in "bool CSU2ASCIIMeshReaderFVM::ReadMetadata(const bool, CConfig *)":

Could not find the keyword "NMARK=".
Check the SU2 ASCII file format.r in the mesh file, however a new error occurs when this happens which is:

ive iterated the model in both vsp and gmsh multiple times and keep running into the same error, ive also attached the vsp model, stl and gmsh file below. any help would be greatly appreciated.

the files related to this are in the google drive below:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folde...usp=share_link

I already tried re-configuring the mesh file manually, and using geometries from the internet incase the issue was with modelling the aircraft in OPENVSP, neither of these seems to help.